# Simple! Why is my msgBox not returning the current year?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write verify the users age for a school project and am having troubles getting the Year(Now()) to actually return the current year.

```
Private Sub cmdOldEnough_Click()

Dim strCalculateAge As String
Dim dtToday As Date

strCalculateAge = Right(inpAge, 4)
dtToday = Year(Now())

MsgBox dtToday

End Sub
```

The Current code returns the date 07/08/1905. Many thanks!

Comment: You are passing `2016` the current year to a date variable therefore you get that because date variable counts from `1` being `31-2-1899` and `2 being `1-1-1900` and so on. Hence `2016` will return that.

Comment: Change `Dim dtToday As Date` to `Dim dtToday As Long` @newguy has already given you the explanation :)

Comment: Note that you can't actually calculate a person's age by subtracting only the year...

Comment: Unfortunately I just learned that! I am trying to incorporate a datediff to get the actual age.

Comment: @newguy what system are you using where 1 = 31-2-1899??

Comment: @MacroMan See this http://imgur.com/PgJXIbf I think there was a typo it returned 31-12-1899

Comment: @newguy on Windows OS 1 should equal 01/01/1900. On Mac/UNIX it's different by one but I've never seen that before..... Dates in Excel/Windows generically are stored as _n_ days from 00/01/1900 so that's odd. Maybe even question worthy. But not taking liability if you ask and get down votes!

Comment: @MacroMan yes even I though it should start from `1/1/1900` but here's a question if that's something related to my  system why did the OP got the same result when passed `2016` ?. I think I/we are missing something very basic but I'll take the risk of asking the question anyway.

Comment: @MacroMan Can you test it on your system before I post the question?

Comment: @newguy very interesting, on my machine 1 = 01/01/1900 *in a worksheet* (as expected) but in the VBE 1 = 31/12/1899 - verified by using `?CDate(1)` in the immediate window. I'd say it's question worthy if it hasn't already been asked

Comment: It never hurts that we all, once again, read oldie but goldie http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `Date`, you need a `Long`:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim dtToday As Long

    dtToday = Year(Now())

    MsgBox dtToday
End Sub
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout  I began my answer before seeing the comments............I will delete my answer.

Comment: No Dont :) Leave it now

Comment: `Sub marine` hahah LOL.