# Why does the date returns "31-12-1899" when 1 is passed to it?

Tags: vba, excel, date

[image]

I am using windows 10 OS excel 13 so in the below code `1` should return `1/1/1900` right ? below it doesn't why.

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375368/simple-why-is-my-msgbox-not-returning-the-current-year?noredirect=1#comment60374031_36375368) question OP passed `2016` and got the same result I got so if there is some error why do I got the same result as OP when I passed `2016` ?

```
Sub ndat()

Dim dt As Date
dt = 2016
Debug.Print "dt is " & dt

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Because the base date (date zero) in all MS Office applications is 12-30-1899, and adding 1 to that date results in 12-31-1899. (You can verify this yourself by putting 0 in an Excel cell and formatting it as a date.)

Comment: @KenWhite then why does MacroMan got 1/1/1900 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375368/simple-why-is-my-msgbox-not-returning-the-current-year?noredirect=1#comment60374031_36375368) in the comments. Also can you do `?CDate(1)` on your system and tell me what you get ?

Comment: @KenWhite is correct about the epoch date - you can read about *why* [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/16/erics-complete-guide-to-vt_date/)

Comment: @Comintern I'm aware of the "Lotus 123 bug" - but why is there a [difference between worksheet and VBE](http://i.imgur.com/tTexpNn.png)?

Comment: @KenWhite 0 in a cell formatted as a date returns `00/00/1900`

Comment: Not in my version of Excel (the version on this particular machine is Excel 2007).

Comment: @MacroMan - Beats me.  I was just pointing out that 12-30-1899 is the epoch date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integers and dates map differently in VBA  than in the worksheet.  For example:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim i As Integer, d As Date
    Dim mgs As String

    msg = ""
    For i = -10 To 10
        d = CDate(i)
        msg = msg & i & vbTab & Format(d, "mm/dd/yyyy") & vbCrLf
    Next i

    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Produces:

[image]

Note you can get dates prior to *1/1/1900*

**EDIT#1:**

This may help to understand the difference.  I put some integers in column **A**.

In **B1**, I put `=A1` and copy down.  I format column **B** to display in date format.

I use this UDF():

```
Public Function VBA_Date(i As Long) As String
    VBA_Date = Format(CDate(i), "mm/dd/yyyy")
End Function
```

To fill column **C**:

[image]

Note the transition between rows #19 and #20

Comment: Not my question, but do you know *why* the zero dates are different? I think that's the real meat in this sandwich.

Comment: @MacroMan  It is not just the zero date!

Comment: Bad phrasing on my part - I mean *why* is the integer-to-date mapping different between the worksheet and VBA?

Comment: @MacroMan  Because the mapping in *VBA* lacks a specific bug.....I will update my Post..................

Comment: @MacroMan  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: So would it be fair to assume that the difference is there because in the *worksheet* there was a requirement for this due to the Lotus 1-2-3 bug, whereas in VBA there has never been a requirement for this backwards compatibilty - therefore theoretically VBA is, and always has been, correct?

Answer (score 6):

It is just the worksheet itself. Or to be correct: The worksheet-functionality!

Quick test:

```
?cdate(1)
1899-12-31 
?format(1,"YYYY-MM-DD")
1899-12-31
?worksheetfunction.Text(1,"YYYY-MM-DD")
1900-01-01
```

But going for todays date does not show this gap:

```
?clng(now)
 42463 
?worksheetfunction.Text(now,"0")
42463
```

That shows that somewhere between 1 and 42463 is a gap (the quick lotus check shows it:

```
?cdate(60) & " --- " & cdate(61)
1900-02-28 --- 1900-03-01
?format(60,"YYYY-MM-DD") & " --- " & format(61,"YYYY-MM-DD")
1900-02-28 --- 1900-03-01
?worksheetfunction.Text(60,"YYYY-MM-DD") & " --- " & worksheetfunction.Text(61,"YYYY-MM-DD")
1900-02-29 --- 1900-03-01
```

Just one last test to show it again:

```
?format("1900-02-28","0") & " --- " & format("1900-03-01","0")
60 --- 61
?worksheetfunction.Text("1900-02-28","0") & " --- " & worksheetfunction.Text("1900-03-01","0")
59 --- 61
```

starting with 61, there is simply now difference in numbers. But the Lotus-Bug adds the 1900-02-29 for "compatibility".

Also: that is a "feature" for excel and has nothing to do with basic, vbscript, vba.......... All other programs work in the correct way and it would get lots of trouble if VBA would not. So for "compatibility" the VBA in excel just does it in the correct way ;)