# Default date is not what I expected for a Date variable initialized with time only

Tags: vba, excel, date

With a `Date` variable, apparently it defaults to `January 1, 0001` if you don't enter a date in a date/time literal.

However, if I choose to display that default date, it shows the date `December 30, 1899` which isn't even an acceptable date in Excel. Here's the code:

```
Sub TimeOfBirth()  
  Dim BirthTime As Date  
  BirthTime = "2:00:00 PM"  
  MsgBox Format(BirthTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")  
End Sub
```

Can anyone explain this? I get that VBA stores a much greater range of dates, but I don't understand why `December 30, 1899` is being displayed?

What's the math/logic there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the date returns "31-12-1899" when 1 is passed to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378476/why-does-the-date-returns-31-12-1899-when-1-is-passed-to-it)

Comment: Also as a useful future advice, `Date` has no literal type character, or identifier character. However, the compiler does implicitly coerce number-literals enclosed with `#` to a date. For example `#01-01-0001#` is a valid `Date`

Comment: Thanks Rawrplus but I still don't get it - the default is set to January 1, 0001 in VBA if you don't specify a date -  so I don't understand how that default translates to December 30, 1899 in Excel? Is January 1, 0001 in VBA technically stored as 0 - and then as a result displayed as December 30, 1899 in Excel? This is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Also, if 0 = December 30, 1899 and 1 = January 1, 1900...what about December 31, 1899?

Comment: Yeah that's sadly kind of misleading thing in documentation as `Date` in VB (Visual Basic) returns `January 1, 001` while in VBA `December 30th, 1899`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel treats date as a number. Since you provide only Time, he assumes that Date = 0.

And Date 0 is December 30, 1899.

#### Edit

---

To answer your question from comments:

1. `Date` defaults to `January 1, 0001` in VB.NET.
2. `Date` default to `December 30, 1899` in VBA and is stored as 0.
3. `Date = 1` not equals to `January 1, 1900`, but to `December 31, 1899`. `January 1, 1900` is equal to `2`. Check code below.

   ```
   Sub TimeOfBirth()
       MsgBox Format(0, "yyyy-mm-dd") '1899-12-30
       MsgBox Format(1, "yyyy-mm-dd") '1899-12-31
       MsgBox Format(2, "yyyy-mm-dd") '1900-01-01
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Setting `Birthtime = 0` is excessive here. `Date` literal automatically defaults to `0` when it is left unassigned.

Comment: Yeah, I know - it is only for explanation purpose.

Comment: Thanks Pm Duda. Please see comment directed to Rawrplus in first answer. I still don't "get it".

Comment: Also, if 0 = December 30, 1899 and 1 = January 1, 1900...what about December 31, 1899?

Comment: No problem at all. Answer acceptance would be appreciated :)